# Timed out waiting for driver server to start error executing Java tests with Circle CI

Tags: java, selenium, maven, pipeline, circleci

I am only starting to use Circle CI tool for running my Java autotests (Selenium, Maven).

My code in Java:

```java
    public void setUp() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        webDriver = new ChromeDriver(setOptions());
        webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        webDriver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        webDriver. manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public ChromeOptions setOptions() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setHeadless(true);
        options.addArguments("enable-automation");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("window-size=1024,768");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        return options;
    }
```

My **config.yml** in **.circleci** directory:

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:16.13.1-browsers
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: mkdir test-reports
      - run:
          name: Download Selenium
          command: curl -O http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.5/selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar
      - run:
          name: Start Selenium
          command: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -log test-reports/selenium.log
          background: true
  test:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/openjdk:11.0
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: build
          command: mvn -B -DskipTests clean package
      # Then run your tests!
      - run:
          name: test
          command: mvn test -Dtest=SignUp
      - store_test_results:
          path: target/surefire-reports
workflows:
  sample:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test
```

**Build** job is finished successfully. But **test** job is failed with next error:

```java
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'df35181eab7e', ip: '172.31.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.13.0-1017-aws', java.version: '11.0.13'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:24652/status] to be available after 20001 ms
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

Could you, please, advise, how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'df35181eab7e', ip: '172.31.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.13.0-1017-aws', java.version: '11.0.13'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:24652/status] to be available after 20001 ms
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

...implies that the driver server didn't get started.

You need to take care of a couple of things here:

- The ***`config.yml`*** file in *`.circleci`* directory mentions about ***Selenium v3.5.3***:

  ```
  - run:
      name: Download Selenium
      command: curl -O http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.5/selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar
  ```

  and

  ```
  - run:
      name: Start Selenium
      command: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -log test-reports/selenium.log
  ```

where as the error stacktrace mentions about ***Selenium v3.141.59***:

```
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
```

You need to crosscheck the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) settings in **Circle CI** configuration and resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for answering! So, did I understand correctly  I need to download Selenium v.3.141.59 instead of v.3.5.3?

Comment: Ideally, you should. Of coarse everything boils down to the requirement captured in the Requirement Specifications and the Test Specification about which version of Selenium to use.

Comment: And could you, please, advise, if I need  also download chromedriver in .yml file?